# Select a row in a DataTable and change the header name to a new name and order by first and last names

Tags: linq, datatable

How do I reassign a header name using linq?  I tried MyHeaderName but that doesn't work.  Also I wanted to sort by first and last name.

```
DataTable dataTable = ...retrieve from some data set... 

var myNames = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select( x => x["first"] & x["last"], "MyHeaderName" ).orderBy("first", "last");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just change the column name for a single `DataRow`. `DataRow`s are tied to their parent `DataTable` (and therefore its columns and column names).

You can change the column name of the `DataTable` which will be reflected in all its `DataRow`s...

```
dataTable.Columns["name"].ColumnName = "new name";
```

It looks like from your edit that you want to have a column containing the full name. You can do so by first creating a new column and then populate the `DataRow` fields in a loop...

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("fullName");
foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    row["fullName"] = row["first"].ToString() + " " + row["last"].ToString();
}
// gets an enumerable of DataRow (the entire row) sorted by first then last
var myNames = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(r => r["first"].ToString())
                 .ThenBy(r => r["last"].ToString());
```

Or you can use LINQ to project to an anonymous object that has a field called `FullName` (you can add more fields that you need)...

```
var myNames = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       .OrderBy(r => r["first"].ToString())
                       .ThenBy(r => r["last"].ToString())
                       .Select(x => new { FullName = x["first"].ToString() + " " + x["last"].ToString() });

foreach (var person in myNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.FullName);
}
```